# ORA-00984: column not allowed here - Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, addition

I want to add a column on an existing table (ORACLE Database) :

```
ALTER TABLE FOA_PARAM_PRODUIT
ADD (LANCEMENT_RAPIDE_DEVIS          VARCHAR2    (1 CHAR)       DEFAULT N)
;
```

I got this error :

```
ADD (LANCEMENT_RAPIDE_DEVIS      VARCHAR2    (1 CHAR)   DEFAULT N)
                                                                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Here are my actuel table :

```
ID_PRODUIT  NUMBER(5,0)
ID_MARCHE   NUMBER(5,0)
ID_BRANCHE  NUMBER(5,0)
COD_PRODUIT VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)
LIB_PRODUIT VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)
TYP_DEBRANCHEMENT   VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
COD_OAV VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
NOM_OAV VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
OPPORTUNITE_OBLIGATOIRE VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)
NOM_EXECUTABLE_OAV  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

I have no column named `LANCEMENT_RAPIDE_OAV`, is there anybody who can help ?

Comment: I guess you mean 'N' as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected command:

```
ALTER TABLE FOA_PARAM_PRODUIT ADD (LANCEMENT_RAPIDE_DEVIS VARCHAR2 (1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N');
```