# Why there are so much restriction on LONG datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Why there are so much restrictions on `LONG` datatype in Oracle? Why it is recommended to use `CLOB` instead of `LONG`?

Comment: @Borr Well, then so as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873934/how-to-trim-characters-from-a-string-in-oracle/27873961#27873961]  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816198/ora-00984-column-not-allowed-here-oracle-database/27816367#27816367, both you have answered.

Comment: The LONG data type has been deprecated. Extending the support for said type isn't happening. Instead you're recommended to use LOBs, CLOB specifically. In Database 12c, you can also extend VARCHAR2 columns up to 32k bytes or characters (assuming single byte storage per character.)

Comment: Thanks thatjeffsmith. I am curious to know why it is deprecated? Are there any performance issues/challenges with LONG? May be I need to study more on CLOB type to get the actual differences between these two.

Comment: You seem to be coming at it from the wrong side. They haven't made LONG worse. LONG was always restrictive and painful; CLOB was added to supersede it as a far superioir data type. There is no reason to leep using LONG now the better CLOB is there, and it is only kept for backward compatibility, as the docs state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to Oracle 7, LONG and LONG RAW were the only data types available to store large amounts of data. The restrictions on LONGs have always been there, and always made using them difficult.

Oracle added large object support in Oracle 8i as a superior data type to replace the old types. Generically these are LOBs, with CLOB superseding LONG, and BLOB superseding LONG RAW (plus BFILE etc.). The current document still explains some of the benefits in the ["Why not use LONGs?" section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_intro.htm#ADLOB45118):

> - LOB Capacity: LOBs can store much larger amounts of data. LOBs can store 4GB of data or more depending on you system configuration. LONG and LONG RAW types are limited to 2GB of data.
> - Number of LOB columns in a table: A table can have multiple LOB columns. LOB columns in a table can be of any LOB type. In Oracle Database Release 7.3 and higher, tables are limited to a single LONG or LONG RAW column.
> - Random piece-wise access: LOBs support random access to data, but LONGs support only sequential access.
> - LOBs can also be object attributes.

From 12c you can have `VARCHAR2` columns of up to 32k, as @thatjeffsmith mentioned in a comment; which will cover a lot of places CLOBs have had to be used in the past where 4k just wasn't quote enough.

Your question seems to imply that Oracle has added restrictions to LONGs. That isn't the case, and you're looking at it the wrong way around. LOBs were introduced partly to overcome the restrictions that LONGs already had, and [the LONG data types are only kept for backward compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201). Anything written since 8i should be using LOBs, and anything older than that should at least have considered converting LONGs to LOBs by now. (Despite the data dictionary still using LONGs internally...)

I'd suggest that if you don't have to maintain a legacy system that is stuck with LONG columns you can pretty much forget about them - don't be tempted to use them in new tables, and there isn't really much point now even playing aroud with them.

Comment: LOB boundary of 4GB is outdated meanwhile. It was valid till Oracle 10g as far as I remember. Today it is `(4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter` e.i. 8 TB to 128 TB

Comment: @Wernfried - true; that quote is from 11gR2 docs, and 12c says the same. It does say 'or more' I suppose, but does rather understate the improvement now.